# How can I set a consistent font for sent messages in Apple Mail Mojave?

Tags: mail.app, mojave, catalina, font

macOS Mojave Mail still ignores a body font for outgoing emails. Rich Text emails show up with Times New Roman font on Windows Outlook clients. Mail does not set a font type, Thus, Windows Outlook uses its default paragraph formatting which falls back to Times New Roman. It's so unprofessional and embarrassing

Using plain text seems to be the only solution. Big downside: No bolding, no highlighting. This has been an ongoing issue since years. There used to be a great plugin called Universal Mailer which is no longer developed.

Any workaround for Apple Mail Mojave and Catalina? I highly appreciate any solution.

Answer (score 1):

People who send plain text mails are heroes to me. There’s no downside there since it respects everyone including screen readers, people who have a font and size preference, etc...

There is a real cost to rtf bloat and html and you are seeing some of that pain here.  My solution is to eschew bu to know some people look down on that as plain text can be rendered horribly as well by some Mail clients.

Sadly, you have to read the room for your intended audience and choose an authoring tool that is copacetic. A third party mail app might be needed if no one has a style tweak that lets you keep the styling features you know you need to communicate effectively. Outlook on Mac does a decent job of hiding that the mail came from Apple if you have the desire to try that.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed in 2020 I am still using plain text emails for consistent emails. I am using my personal "markup like" format e.g. * # for highlighting text. In reality you deal with Outlook users, though. In some cases you have to highlight text within a email. Switching to RTF mode to add 1-2 List item in Apple Mail leads to embarrassing Times New Roman emails! I do agree 100% regarding bloating html/span tag mails. Anyway it's not the answer I was looking for. It's kind of disappointed that there's still no solution available.

Comment: I agree - let’s hope anyone has a better answer with functionality and grace. Thanks for the good discussion @howdytom

Answer (score 1):

If you want the recipient to see your chosen font and other styling, you can achieve this in Mail by setting it individually for each outgoing message, or perhaps by saving it as "stationery" to use as a template.  If you want to be able to set this for all outgoings by default, the solution is to use another email client like Outlook.

Comment: Thanks, switching to Mac Outlook, Thunderbird/Postbox, Airmail, mail client seems to be the only option. I don't like none of them. For now I am sticking with plain text emails.